# Dynamically resize label based on lines of text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am finding it surprisingly hard to resize a label containing newlines based on the quantity of lines and text.  It displays fine in a large enough textview.  However, I'd like the economy of sizing the label--or I'd be happy with resizing a textview--exactly.

This is the code I am using from an answer on SO but it is having no effect on the size of the label. Would appreciate any suggestions on how to make this work:

```
NSString *list = self.list.list;
// use font information from the UILabel to calculate the size    
UITextView *view=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 10)]; 
//make random size view
view.text=list;
CGSize size=[view sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(280, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
// create a frame that is filled with the UILabel frame data
CGRect newFrame = _listLabel.frame;
// resizing the frame to calculated size
newFrame.size.height = size.height;
// put calculated frame into UILabel frame
_listLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the frame of your label with reference of a newly created UITextView, it will create a useless object in your memory, to set the label frame according to your text just use this 2 line of code

```
lbl.numberOfLines=0;
[lbl sizeToFit];
```

It will make the label as large as your text.

Comment: Your observation makes sense but this code did not make it resize.  In Storyboard, number of lines is also 0.  Is there anything else that could be throwing it off?

Comment: is your label text got trimmed like `...` in the end ?? Also are you using autolayouts ?

Comment: Not trimmed.  No autolayouts.  However, it looks like the IB height setting is overriding sizetofit.  I don't know how to remove a heigh setting in storyboard.  If I set it to 0, the label disappears and if to a large number the label expands accordingly.

Comment: Will you edit you question and post the image of you XIB

Comment: There is nothing in the xib.  Just the label.  Which settings of the various inspectors are you interested in?

Comment: Fifth one Size Inspector

Answer (score 0):

You really should use autolayout. 
Just constrain the label where you need and let UIKit do it's job.

Here an example:

I set a top space and a leading margin constraints
[image: I set a top space and a leading margin constraints]

Then I added a width constraint and then I added some more text

[image]

As you can see the label resized itself as it knows how much text it has inside and how much space it occupies.

Comment: what did you do in the size inspector and identity inspector.  Is it okay to put lines zero and ignore values in size inspector?  I don't see any way to leave values in size inspector blank.

Comment: Size inspector doesn't mean much when you use autolayout.